# apache velocity: remap $ and # keys

Tags: velocity

I wonder if it is possible to remap "$" and "#" to other keys.

sample:

```
#set( $foo = "bar" )
```

I want to use other keys because those interfere with another syntax of a script I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ and # characters are not configurable in Velocity. Even at compile time, it would at least imply to recompile the parser, and make a full code review for standalone $ and # chars...

That said:

- Velocity does cope pretty well with syntax fragments it cannot parse, like jQuery $ object. It just render them as is, and most of the time it does the job.
- You can escape your other script's sensitive characters whenever needed, for instance by using the EscapeTool: `${esc.d}` for dollar, `${esc.h}` for hash.